app crash on FireBase FireStore connection
I'm trying to connect to firebase, but the app just keeps crashing. I understand I must be having some misaligned dependencies, but I believe I took the right versions according to:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android
The Build.gradle.kts contain:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.6.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.25"
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2"
}
dependencies {
    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.3.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:25.1.0")
}

As for the project level:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
}


The code I'm using is the following, as as proof of concept..:
fun checkWhitelistByEmail(
    email: String,
    onAccessGranted: () -> Unit,
    onAccessDenied: () -> Unit,
    scope: CoroutineScope // Pass the coroutine scope from outside
) {
    val db = Firebase.firestore
//    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    Log.d("FirestoreCheck", "Firestore instance initialized")


    db.collection("whitelisted_users")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                Log.d("FirestoreCheck", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w("FirestoreCheck", "Error getting documents.", exception)
        }
}

But it keeps crashing with:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)

Process: com.flashc_ai.FlahsC_AI, PID: 5439
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (25.1.0).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:546)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/grpc/InternalGlobalInterceptors;
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:3)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.lambda$runBidiStreamingRpc$0$com-google-firebase-firestore-remote-FirestoreChannel(FirestoreChannel.java:146)


etc....
Any idea how I can arrange that, I'm really stuck with this bug since days and nothing works no matter what I try. Note, firebaseAuth works fine, so the connection setting is OK.
Thanks!
I tried specifying the versions of the modules imported, tried to simplify the code to make a proof of concept...

thanks for the answers!
In the end, I found the winning constellation, and don't dare to touch it anymore for now :D
build.gradle(app):
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.6.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.25"
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2"
}
dependencies {
    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.3.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.68.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.68.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.68.0")
}

build.gradle(project):
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
}

Function:
fun checkEmail(
    doctype: String,
    onDocFound: () -> Unit,
    onDocNotFound: () -> Unit
) {
    val db = Firebase.firestore

    db.collection("my_collection")
        .document(doctype)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                // Document  exists
                onDocFound()
            } else {
                // Document doesn't exist
                onDocNotFound()
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.d("FirestoreCheck", "error: $e")
            // Handle any errors
        }
}


The issue you're encountering seems to be related to the io.grpc library, which is often used by Firebase Firestore for its networking layer. This could be a result of version mismatches between the libraries you're using. Also, since FirebaseAuth works fine, it’s likely a version conflict rather than a network issue. You could try updating to the latest version to ensure compatibility between Firebase components.
If updating and managing the dependencies doesn't resolve the problem, try testing Firestore operations on a separate project or environment to rule out other causes.


Project level gradle file is fine.

build.gradle(app)
a)Inside of plugin block-> paste
id("com.google.gms.google-services")


b)Inside of dependencies block ->paste
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.3.0"))

just use these two dependencies , auth dependency you can directly import in your activity file.
As for code , I am Providing you a code block from my sample test app
val currentUser = auth.currentUser
val userId = currentUser?.uid
try {
                val userId = auth.currentUser?.uid
                //val currentTotal = total.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
                val addedAmount = amount.text.toString().toInt()

                // Update total and save to SharedPrefs
                val newTotal = total.text.toString().toInt() + addedAmount
                total.text = newTotal.toString()
                SharedPrefs.getInstance(context = this).save("Amount", newTotal.toString())
                val expense = hashMapOf(
                    "description" to desc.text.toString(),
                    "amount" to amount.text.toString().toInt(),
                    "timestamp" to System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    "total" to newTotal,
                    "date" to TxtDate.text.toString()
                )
                userId?.let {
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(it)
                        .collection("expenses")
                        .add(expense)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            clearEditTexts()
                            MessageUtilDialog.errorMessagedialog(this,"Expense Added")
                        }.addOnFailureListener {
                            MessageUtilDialog.errorMessagedialog(this,"Expense Not Added")
                        }

                        }
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                // Handle invalid number input
                MessageUtilDialog.errorMessagedialog(this, "Invalid number format")
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid number format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

Check this code and try to make the connection (Firebase.Firestore.getInstance().collection("your firestore db name")
